# Swagger SpringMVC Integration (Failed to load @PostConstruct method)

Tags: spring, api, spring-mvc, swagger

I am trying to integrate [swagger-springmvc](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc) 0.9.5 with SpringMVC 3.2 project with XML configuration.

My app-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="ht...

<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>


<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.info.v1.rest.endpoint"/>
<bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig" />


</beans>
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.mangofactory.swagger.models.property.field.FieldModelPropertyProvider.propertiesForSerialization(FieldModelPropertyProvider.java:54)
com.mangofactory.swagger.models.property.provider.DefaultModelPropertiesProvider.propertiesForSerialization(DefaultModelPropertiesProvider.java:31)
com.mangofactory.swagger.models.DefaultModelProvider.properties(DefaultModelProvider.java:104)
com.mangofactory.swagger.models.DefaultModelProvider.modelFor(DefaultModelProvider.java:54)
com.mangofactory.swagger.readers.ApiModelReader.execute(ApiModelReader.java:70)
com.mangofactory.swagger.readers.ApiModelReader.execute(ApiModelReader.java:38)
com.mangofactory.swagger.core.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:13)
com.mangofactory.swagger.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:98)
com.mangofactory.swagger.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing.initialize(SwaggerApiResourceListing.java:72)
com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin.initialize(SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin.java:427)
...
```

I started to debug, and realized the following:

1. objectMapper is null
2. setObjectMapper is never called
3. [setup()](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc/blob/8e9b3a5a8b3afb8ad363922785dce18888cf24e7/swagger-springmvc/src/main/java/com/mangofactory/swagger/configuration/JacksonSwaggerSupport.java) is never called, although it has @PostConstruct annotation.

I found three posts with the same error but none of them seem relevant.
Am I forgetting something? I am new to SpringMVC framework.

Sidenote: I also experimented with swagger-springmvc 0.6.6 and managed to get it work.

Comment: For starters why do you need the message converters? try removing that and see if it helps

Comment: It also does not work with <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: After your update, it seems like the value of the objectMapper needs to either be a **ref** to a bean or an inlined bean. ```value=classpath*...``` is definitely not right. Also it needs to be an instance of an ```ObjectMapper```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had similar issues in a OSGi / blueprint driven environment.
For some reason "touching" the JacksonSwaggerSupporty bean causes the PostConstruct method to be called correctly.
This is not nice - but a working workaround. The bean that setups our swagger and spring contexts in OSGi contains this:

```
        // for some reason this line causes @PostConstruct to be called on bean correctly! 
    applicationContext.getBean(JacksonSwaggerSupport.class); // Do not remove!
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your answer which helped me to find solution. This is what worked for my XML configuration: `<bean class="com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.JacksonSwaggerSupport" init-method="setup" />`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your configuration to pass in an instance of an object mapper and see if that helps

```java
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean id="messageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" >
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="[replace with default ObjectMapper or your custom subclass]" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I edited my question with more information and included my mapper.xml file . Still struggling with connecting the objectMapper. Any ideas?

Comment: If I ref to `<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" />` I get the same NullPointerException. What can I else try?